# eloquent withcount not showing count

Tags: laravel

I followed this from laravel daily https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-withcount-get-related-records-amount/ I get no errors but the count isn't showing up, when dd  $post->likes_count I get null. The search isn't working either when filtering for likes and I guess it's the same issue. I don't want to use count() because I get like 40 queries instead of 8, so any solutions to this and why this isn't working?

```
<span class="leading-none text-sm font-semibold mr-2 mt-1 text-white">{{ $post->likes_count }}</span>
      
<span class="leading-none text-sm font-semibold mr-2 mt-1 text-white">{{ $post->comments_count</span>
      
public function render()
{
        return view('livewire.posts', [
            'posts' => Post::withCount(['comments', 'likes'])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->paginate(5)
        ]);
    }
```

the search:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $search = request()->input('title');

        $posts = Post::query()->latest();

        if ($search) {
            $posts->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . request()->title. '%');
        } elseif ($request->has('likes')) {
            $posts->withCount('likes')->orderByDesc('likes_count');
        } elseif ($request->has('latest')) {
            $posts->orderByDesc('created_at');
        } elseif ($request->has('follow')) {
            $posts->whereIn('user_id', $request->user()->following()->pluck('users.id'));
        }

        return view('welcome', [
            'posts' => $posts->paginate(12)
        ]);
    }
```

Post modal:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Spatie\Image\Image;
use Spatie\Image\Manipulations;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    use Notifiable;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'active' => 'boolean',
    ];

    public function likedBy(User $user)
    {
        return $this->likes->contains('user_id', $user->id);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function incrementReadCount()
    {
        $this->increment('reads');
    }

    public function publish()
    {
        $this->active = true;
        $this->save();
    }

    public function unpublish()
    {
        $this->active = false;
        $this->save();
    }

    public function storeImage(?UploadedFile $image)
    {
        if ($image) {
            if ($this->image) {
                Storage::delete($this->image);
            }

            $this->image = $image->store('public/photos');

            Image::load(Storage::path($this->image))
                ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CONTAIN, 718, 718)
                ->save();

            $this->save();
        }
    }

    public function getImageUrlAttribute()
    {
        return $this->image
            ? Storage::url($this->image)
            : url('img/default_post_cover.jpg');
    }
}
```

Comment: add here `post modal`

Comment: Are you sure `comments` and `likes` exist for that `Post` owned by that `User`? What happens when you `dd(Post::withCount(['comments', 'likes'])->paginate());` in the `render()` function of the `LiveWire` component? Does `comments_count` and `likes_count` attribute exist then?

Comment: @EricLandheer I had to be logged in for the dd to work. I get the posts with likes and comments